# How to deploy application over cloud using cloudstack

Tags: web-applications, deployment, cloud, apache-cloudstack

I complete install cloudstack on my system. Now  I wanna know about "How to deploy application over cloud using cloudstack?"

Anyone have any idea about this please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would deploy your application within CloudStack the same as you would within any other cloud. A few examples:

- For "legacy" applications that do not take advantage of the scalability or other functions of a cloud, spin up one or more VMs with appropriate CPU, memory, and disk resources and the appropriate OS. Login, set up the systems as necessary and off you go.
- For a "devops" style deployment, one would define the application and it's dependencies within the automation software of their choice (eg Chef, Puppet, Anisible, etc). As with the legacy app, VMs would have to be created with the appropriate resources, and then the automation agent is run on each VM instead of configuring the systems by hand.
- For a more "modern" cloud-based deployment of the application, the user do some combination of the steps above to get the various pieces up and running - in a dev or stage environment. Once the systems are set, images of the system are made within CloudStack. Using CloudStack's API, the user writes programs (or uses existing applications) to programmatically manage the creation/destruction of production systems from the images.

I've left networking out of the above examples. Depending on the CloudStack zone setup, one could also configure NAT, firewalling, VPCs, load balancing, and/or autoscaling of various parts of the application.